# java applet calling system dll stop working on Internet explorer 11

Tags: javascript, dll, applet, internet-explorer-11, wacom

I have a java applet exposing methods that i call from javascript 
The java applet is working fine in internet explorer 9 , in chrome and in firefox .

In internet explorer 11 , methods from applet that use dlls (to call a wacom device in my case are not working ), other methods are callable and working fine .

Are there any change in Internet explorer 11 that causes this issue ?!

Edit : the problem is actually simpler and could be described as this :

In IE11 , if an applet is embeded in an iframe , it's methods are not visible from parent document .

Comment: *"In IE11 , if an applet is embeded in an iframe , it's methods are not visible from parent document ."* This sounds like a protection against [cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), and an overdue one at that.

Comment: Yes , there is a property of iframe to allow scripting  [sandbox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772930(v=vs.85).aspx) but it does not change the applet behaviour .